# Grouping from a separate table

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I need to Count the number of students who have achieved 80% or more in the first semester in each year. I have two tables, one with student details called tblStudents and the other with their grades called tblStudentSubjectMarks. Now, there are the years of each student under the column AcYear in tblStudents and the first semester marks are stored in the column E1 in tblStudentSubjectMarks. I wrote this to display all students that got an 80% or higher regardless of their year, just as one result:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [80%]
FROM tblStudentSubjectMarks
WHERE E1 >= 80;
```

The output is: 1553

Now, I want to group the data according to the AcYear (which is the current year of the student) so that it displays how many people in first year got an A, how many people in second year, and so on. The problem with that is, when I try this,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [80%]
FROM tblStudentSubjectMarks, tblStudents
WHERE E1 >= 80
GROUP BY AcYear;
```

The output is three rows of values like 442605. Obviously this output is incorrect.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're implicitly doing a cross join, meaning all marks for all students are being associated with each student.  You need to limit your results by specifying how a record in one table is related to a record in the other table.  For example, if StudentID is a column uniquely identifying a student, you could add a WHERE condition AND'ed to the existing one, so that your WHERE clause would be something like:

```
WHERE E1 >= 80 AND tblStudentSubjectMarks.StudentID = tblStudents.StudentID
```